# Applicable to [object] for [purpose]

Tags: word-choice

My question is about the word *applicable*.

Is the following construction correct?

> This method is applicable to [object] for [purpose].

For example:

> Our method may be applicable to medium-sized lake for evaluating mid-layer processes.

If this is incorrect, is there a way to express the "for [purpose]" part of this sentence without changing the sentence dramatically?

Comment: Seems OK to me, except that in your query sentence you also need the  article 'a' before 'medium-sized lake'.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I worried so much about "to" and "for" that I forgot "a".

Comment: Either that, or use the plural: _applicable to medium-sized lakes_ ...

Answer (score 1):

*To* indicates what you use your method on (lakes); *for* indicates what you expect that method to achieve (evaluating processes).

Instead of *applicable to* you could write *used on* without much change in meaning, if any:

> Our method may be used on medium-sized lakes for evaluating mid-layer processes.

This makes *used for* more obvious:

> Our method may be used on medium-sized lakes.
>   Our method may be used for evaluating mid-layer processes.

If *applicable for* is too awkward or unusual, substitute something else (like *used on/for*), but the ellipsis in your sentence avoids actually using the collocation *applicable for*.